# Junit4: Running a Suite of particular Test methods

Tags: testing, junit, suite

Is there a way to create a suite of test *methods*, not just test classes?

I'd like to put together a test suite that just runs particular tests methods from a test class. I don't see a way to do this from my limited junit knowledge and from searching the web.

Comment: Just some little stupid thought: Create new class and paste important methods you want to run from various tests, it's complete fake but it should work for you ...

Answer (score 8):

Use **Categories** feature in JUnit4.

Example: if some methods scattered both in `ATest` and `BTest` are expected to executed :

```
//Define Categories
@RunWith(Categories.class)  
@IncludeCategory(NeedTest.class)  
@SuiteClasses({ ATest.class,  BTest.class })  
class MySuite{
...
}
```

Then in `ATest` and `BTest`, annotate your expect methods as:

```
@Test
@Category(NeedTest.class)  
public void test()
```

When you run `MySuite`, only the methods annotated with `@Category(NeedTest.class)` will be executed. Of course, you could create multiple test categories,

ps: NeedTest.class is just a marker class, it can be any class.

Comment: Hi Shengyuan, if we use our customize runner, then this feature will be disabled for us except we implement this feature at our own runner, right?

Comment: How to actually run the MySuite class?

Comment: This is so inconvenient when compared to TestNg test suite xml file. Why does Junit not allow us to select methods without annotating the test methods ? Has this inconvenience been fixed in Junit 5?